# phpmyadmin connection issue between EC2 and RDS on AWS

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have followed the procedure on this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bz-4wTGD2_Q
but for some reason I get an error when I reach minute 5:03. See attached error. Could it be due to security groups? In the video it only says 'wide open'  [image: screeshot]

Comment: Did you configure the Security Group for the RDS server to allow access from the EC2 server? I'm not going to watch the video, post your actual security group settings in your question.